# Callout is opened in wrong location after changing the map center

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

When the user selects an item from a table, I change the center of the map to the selected item's location, and select the matching annotation programmatically. This causes the annotation call out to open on the map.

```
mapView.centerCoordinate = itemCoordinate
mapView.selectAnnotation(itemAnnotation, animated: true)
```

My problem is that the callout is opened in the previous place on the map, as if the callout is first opened and then the map moves (without moving the callout)

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to select the annotation after a small delay like this:

```
let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
   mapView.selectAnnotation(itemAnnotation, animated: true)
}
```

Or select the annotation without animation should work too:

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(itemAnnotation, animated: false)
```

Comment: Thank you! your first solution works great! the second solution did not work for me